# Eclipse says "filename too long" (which is false) when compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, eclipse-indigo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)

Using Eclipse (Indigo for Java EE), when I clean all projects (to compile them again) I get the following error :

> 'DataNucleus Enhancer' has encountered a problem
>   Cannot run program "C:\jdk7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\0-MS"):
>   CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long (==> in
>   english : the filename or extension is too long)

As you can see, I tried using the shortest path possible, but Eclipse still says the same thing. One similiar problem reported talks about configuring the ORM (using Google App Engine) but I think this is a different problem.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Here is the LOG :

```
!ENTRY com.google.appengine.eclipse.core 4 0 2012-06-26 08:17:23.137
!MESSAGE Cannot run program "C:\jdk7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\0-MS"): CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\jdk7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\0-MS"): CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.ProcessUtilities.launchProcessAndActivateOnError(ProcessUtilities.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.orm.enhancement.EnhancerJob.runInWorkspace(EnhancerJob.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, Nom de fichier ou extension trop long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:188)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the project command line

> -startupUrl MananaSeguro.html -war C:\0-MS\war -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO
>   -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngine

The VM arguments

> -Xmx512m -javaagent:C:\shortGAE-1.6.4\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -XX:-UseSplitVerifier

And the ORM properties (App Engine), there is just one folder :

> src/

Comment: I think i've seen this before but I can't remember. Is there any full log for such error? It would be helpful to trace the problem

Comment: It's probably complaining about one of the files that is a parameter to the Java compilation or run request.  Eclipse directories tend to get long and tedious, and you encounter this problem fairly regularly.  (One of many reasons I don't care that much for Eclipse.)

Comment: I added the log, I do not know if it is enought...

Comment: It's not the filename that's too long, but the whole command line.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot (it is now precised in the question), 'DataNucleus Enhancer' has encountered a problem. I also added the command line of the project and the ORM property (because I have seen in another post that it could be the problem. In my src/ directory, I have the resource directory that contains images etc...but not some too long filename).

Comment: Ok, THE WHOLE COMMAND LINE IS : 

-startupUrl MananaSeguro.html 
-war C:\0-MS\war 
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" 
-logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 
-port 8888 -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher com.mananaseguro.MananaSeguro

Comment: The only suggestion that I have is to make sure your workspace is a short directory like C:\wksp (for Windows).  The Windows default is a rather long directory name with embedded spaces.