# Ant Javadoc task fails

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

Hello I have a simple ant build script to generate javadoc for a bunch of projects.

The ant script is:

```
<project name="javadocs" default="doc" basedir=".">
```

What it looks like is happening is that Javadoc is being invoked with each java file as part of the parameter list, obviously this won't work because Windows has a limit on the size of the parameter that you can pass to programs.  Any help appreciated as to how to make this work.

Comment: Call the javadoc task repeatedly, with different params. Alternatively, call each project's javadoc task from a parent build file.

Comment: How can I have Javadoc resolve and link classes between projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning of your stack-trace is informative:

`C:\work\icade_svn\build_javadoc.xml:19: Javadoc failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin\javadoc.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`

It seems there is good information related to this problem:

https://www.google.com/search?q=CreateProcess+error%3D206%2C+The+filename+or+extension+is+too+long

Including this potential work-around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598074/2736496

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: OK so I was able to get around the problem by concatenating all my folders into the sourcepath attribute of the javadoc task.

Comment: I'm glad to hear you worked it out. And thank you for accepting my answer.