# Cannot deploy new Liferay theme "The filename or extension is too long"

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I'm new to Liferay and Eclipse, and I'm trying to do some simple theme development. However, once I right click my theme (which I just created) and go to Liferay->SDK->deploy I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\sdk6.2\build-common-plugin.xml:482: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sdk6.2\build-common.xml:993: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sdk6.2\build-common.xml:299: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sdk6.2\build-common.xml:1783: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sdk6.2\build-common.xml:175: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\jre7\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

I was using a longer path for my SDK and JRE7 but reduced it to what you see in the above error message (to no avail). Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main

Answer (score 3):

Reconfigure your SDK folder, try to use a label for it  without any "." or special char.

For example:
C:\liferay\sdk621\

And tell us your results...it could be a windows/ant path problem...