# CreateProcess error=206

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am using SpringToolSuite 3.3.0 and this is a desktop application in java. I use to run my project from "Run -> Run configuration" . My project was running OK for some time. But from last few days, when I try to run my project using "Run -> Run configuration-> Main tab -> Run", a pop up comes up saying 

***Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files(X86)\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\projects\arm\src\arm-positionBuilder"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long***

I look for this issue on this website but could not found solution for it. I am using Maven for build. Please advise what changes should I do in project configuration to resolve it.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows bug. In any case, both your JDK and STS are extremely out of date; I suggest upgrading both as a first step.

Comment: how hard did you look? Googling your error message the first hit is to this web site, and specifically this question which is exactly your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10519558/1570834.

Comment: By the way, you've asked 19 questions, 18 of which have 1 or more answers, but you haven't [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) a single answer. It would be appreciated by everyone if you could [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) any of the answers that actually solved your problem (you are allowed to accept your own answers).

Comment: Maybe the command line for Windows that gets generated behind the scenes is too long for the Windows limits. Did you try the workaround with setting the classpath via an environment variable?

Comment: My project is using Maven Dependencies which has so many files in it. Now in my project, This "Maven Dependencies" is included in classpath through Run->Run Configurations->classpath. I believe this "Maven Dependencies" makes my classpath very long. Is there any way I can include "Maven Dependencies" in classpath and stil my classpath length is short.

Answer (score 0):

Make (configuration) fork = false in pom.xml