# JavaExec task and folder classpath scan using wildcards

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

So I have a folder that has many jar files. And I have to use these jar files in classpath for java exec task. But it gives me -

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TestProj:runTest'.
 A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\
java.exe''
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is
too long
```

I am doing something like

```
def jarFiles = files { file('testDir').listFiles() }
task runTest(type: JavaExec) {
   main = 'Main'
   classpath = jarFiles 
}
```

I've tried to use '/*' in path but gradle throws exception

```
Could not normalize path for file....
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: This is probably not a gradle question but rather Windows-specific problem. Have You already seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main ?

Comment: I also tried this in cygwin. Same error....

Comment: When I provide path to a folder in javaexec classpath it does not consider all jar files in it. So I have to do listfile and provide each one in the class path which is too large.

Comment: I know that you've tried wildcard but I've prepared demo: https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29407414, could you please clone the repo and execute `gradle runMain`? If it works, that is teh answer.

Comment: Same thing `Could not determine the dependencies of task ':runMain'.
> Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\athakur\Desktop\TempDump\stackoverflow\2
9407414\libs\*'.`

Comment: What about `/*` instead of `\*`?

Comment: Yes your code is exactly the same `classpath = files { project.file('libs/*')`. Since I am using windows it is resolved like that.

Comment: Ok, so with both `\` and `/` it does not work on windows, yes?

Comment: Nope. Does not work with either.