# Getting error whence I used Endpoint.publish

Tags: java

I am trying to get wsdl from this. Getting this error

> Exception occurred executing command line. Cannot run program
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\EMUKTAT\Project1\TestMart"): CreateProcess error=206, The
>   filename or extension is too long

Here is the code:

```
public class TestMartpublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:58065/prod", new ProductCatalog());

    }
```

Comment: checkout this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main

Answer (score 0):

This issue is likely that your classpath is now very long:

The error message might not quite correct. It could be that the command line length has exceeded Windows limits.

Windows command-lines are restricted to 32,768 characters. An immediate workaround might be to put your workspace / checkout in your disk's root (e.g., c:\ws) to try to shorten pathnames as much as possible.

refer to : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2912

Regards,