# Adding aws-java-sdk dependency to Grails project, fails with create-process:error=206

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails

I want to try to introduce the `aws-java-sdk` dependency in Grails to meet my needs. When I write the `aws-java-sdk` dependency information in the `build.gradle` file, `error=206` appears. I tried to introduce other dependencies without giving an error. I am sure that it is a problem with `aws-java-sdk`.

```
dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:4.0.0.M1'
    //lombok begin
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'

    //google json begin
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    //jsoup begin
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

    //aws begin
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.1.0'

    //springa actuator && data-jpa
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.3.RELEASE'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.15.1"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}
```

You can see `'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.0'`.

And the error for task `bootRun` is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'E:\40-jdk\bin\java.exe''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 12.627 secs
CreateProcess error=206, File name or extension is too long。
```

I dont kown what's matter and I am new to Grails,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)