# Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project pixelperfectapi: Could not exec java: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\bin\java.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Comment: I'm totally stuck :( please help

Comment: In 2020, why are you using Java 8U11 (from July-2014)?   Go to adoptopenjdk.org, download the latest java 8 jdk, and install it.  Chances are good your problem goes away

Comment: because the application i'm working on requires that version only

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that your program only works with Java 8 update 11, and if it really does, you should demand from whoever wrote it to fix the problems that don't allow it to run on newer Java 8 updates. Continuing to run on Java 8 update 11 is a security risk.

Comment: Minimally, as a developer, I'd check to see what happens if you used the current JVM.  Maybe it fixes it, and maybe it doesn't, but I'd definitely want to know.

Comment: Minimally, as a developer, I'd check to see what happens if you used the current JVM.  Maybe it fixes it, and maybe it doesn't, but I'd definitely want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your classname is too large. However this thread may help: [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main)