# Execution failed for task bootRun

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

Whenever I am executing Gradle bootRun in command prompt or Intellij Idea I am getting the following error

- What went wrong

```
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe''
```

- This is the Stacktrace

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe''
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)

Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
  at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
  ... 2 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\My Documents\HadI\Fairtech\michelin_sg"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
  at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
  ... 5 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
  ... 6 more
```

- My Environment

```
Java: 1.8.271
Gradle: 4.10.1
Work Environment: Intellij Idea

I have tried googling but still can't find a solution.
Thanks in Advance
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519558/createprocess-error-206-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long-when-running-main Might help

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestion.I tried all possible ways still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try upgrading the Gradle to 6.0?

Comment: Hi @vaibhavsahu.Thank you for your reply. The problem is if I upgrade to higher version some of the dependencies are deprecating