# Too long filename or extension running Maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have opened a maven project in Netbeans 16 - the project is `deeplearning4j-examples`

When I try to run one of the main classes I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project dl4j-examples: Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" (in directory "C:\deeplearning4j-examples\dl4j-examples"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long -> [Help 1]

Comment: Have you researched this error? Does this help: [CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long when running main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10519558/12567365)? And you can search for other [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=CreateProcess+error+206,+The+filename+or+extension+is+too+long+site:stackoverflow.com) on SO.

Comment: yes - I have looked at other scenarios with a similar problem but I find the suggestions quite confusing and don't know what to exactly try

Comment: See Bug Report [NETBEANS-5208 Fix for java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5208) which describes the issue you face when using Deeplearning4j on NetBeans. The bug report is unresolved, but you can try this helpful suggestion posted in the comments: _"As a workaround I am adding **exec.longClasspath=true** to the run actions of my maven project"_. If that works please consider posting and accepting an answer to your own question, because having accepted answers is more helpful for the SO community.

Comment: [This is a link to the relevant Maven documentation](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#longClasspath) for **<longClasspath>**.